# ShuffleText Highlight Information/Documentation

Tags: .net

Does anyone have copies of documentation for *ShuffleText.com*'s ***ShuffleText.Highlight.Express*** .NET library? The library is used for fuzzy searching in an open source project that I am modifying. I wish to understand *ShuffleText*'s API more in depth, but I cannot locate **any** documentation online.

ShuffleText.com looks like they went out of business. All URL references to them direct to GoDaddy landing pages.

[ShuffleText.com](http://shuffletext.com/) (GoDaddy)

[ShuffleText blog](http://blog.shuffletext.com/) (GoDaddy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have zip-archive "Highlight Express Non Commercial .NET 2.0.zip" (4.Dec 2007, downloaded 16.April 2008) with folder "Documentation", contains "Getting Started.htm" and "Highlight.Express.Documentation.chm" and another folder "Examples" with subfolder "ASP.NET AJAX Example" and "Windows Forms Example"

Have also copy from website: "Faq.aspx.htm"

mailto: 
ulimaier (at ) buecher-boerse (dot) com

regards

Ulrich Maier